# Trying to get summary variables into a table

Tags: r

So I'm working on a project that looks at the spaces of different car parking spaces. So essentially, I would like the variables from summary (mean, quantile, IQR, sd, max, min, median) into a table that when I run it is comes up as a table with all the different variables for each of my Carpark spaces.

I've tried the following code (I saw it in another Stack Overflow question)

```
newlist <-list(mean, quantile, IQR, sd, max, min, median)
val <- lapply(newlist, function(fn) fn(densities))
```

But the error that comes up is that `fn(densities)` is not found.

Comment: could you provide example data and the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
summary <- function(x) {
  funs <- c(mean, median, sd, mad, IQR)
  lapply(funs, function(f) f(x, na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

Only for numeric variables:

```
sapply(mtcars, function(x) { if(is.numeric(x)) summary(x) })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, only problem is that all my data bar one column is numeric and now the problem is saying that all the data needs to be numeric. Would there be a way to use this function minus the Date_Time column

Comment: Perfect thank you so much that worked there, I was wondering what would I need to do to get this summary into a data file, so I could get it in a nice table format.

Comment: Just accepted it there, cant upvote as I'm too new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I look forward to see if you know how to put it into a table format, thanks.

Comment: data.frame(sapply(mtcars, function(x) { if(is.numeric(x)) summary(x) })). Just wrap the output inside the data.frame function. Or what kind of table do you want?

Comment: Just tried it there and it looks super interesting but I was thinking more of a table to show of the values without a diagram kinda like = Parnell- Mean =365 - Median = 455 etc.

Comment: you could use the `transpose` function to flip the table, or use a visual package if that´s what you desire.